# How can i know if a midi input is connected to a midi output?

Tags: c#, api, winapi, audio, midi

I'm making a midi editor which has a dialog for connecting/disconnecting midi inputs to outputs, so the user can have other programs running midi with the same input echoed via virtual midi ports, like maple.

It uses the midiConnect function, but I want to show in the UI, the current midi connections that already exist.

The only method that I can think is to try to connect every input to every output, and if the function returns an error, it means that the connection already exist, but this is a little messy and it can change the state of the current connections obviously.

Is there a way for retrieving which input is connected to which output?

Comment: Such routing functionality isn't built-in.  Plus, drivers can sometimes be used to send output to multiple listeners.  It is driver-dependent.

Comment: the connections are working, the midi routing is fine. The only thing i need is to know is wich connections already exist, and wich input is to connected to wich output, with the only purpose for showing it on the user interface.

Comment: ... but what is making these connections?

Comment: the midiConnect function from the midi api here's the link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798446(v=vs.85).aspx